# Match a number >= column A and < column B Return column C #

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to pull the number out of column C by matching a value to greater than or equal to from column A and then less than column B.

```
>=  <   Pull code       
5   10  1       22
10  15  2       
15  20  3       0
20  25  4       
25  30  5       
30  35  6       
35  40  7       
40  45  8       
45  50  9       
50  55  10      
55  60  11      
60  65  12
```

So the 22 should return a 4 but it returns a zero if I change the 22 to 56 it should give me 11. I have tried many different formulas like index and match also tried vlookup the latest one is

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,">=" & E2,B:B,"<" & G14)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your columns overlap so not sure how you handle the boundary values, but here is a formula you can try, adjust the ranges to suit

=INDEX(C1:C12,MATCH(D1,A1:A12,1))

Comment: It should be noted this requires the range to be sorted in the ascending order, and it will return the last entry if a too big value is provided (e.g. `100` in your example).

Comment: @GSerg - yes, thanks I should have pointed that out. The formula could be adapted to take into account the latter.

Comment: the real table is extremely huge I just shortened it to get to the point. thank you for the answer I will try this out and update how it goes

Comment: just tried it this works amazing thank you so much. This whole time I thought index and match wouldn't work because I needed to check both columns a huge duh moment. I am going to see if I can adapt it myself for the too big value.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, set up a [`DGET`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DGET-function-455568bf-4eef-45f7-90f0-ec250d00892e) criteria range:

```
+------------+-----------+
| >=         | <         |
+------------+-----------+
| ="<=" & D2 | =">" & D2 |
+------------+-----------+
```

and use `=DGET(A1:C13, C1, that_criteria_range)`.

It does not require the range to be sorted and will return an error if the record is not found or if more than one found.

Comment: I am a little lost on how to use the criteria range portion

Comment: @M.Phaneuf Put that into four cells (2x2) somewhere on the sheet. The first row must be the captions from the dataset table, the second row is the criteria that are build from the cell where you enter your number to search.